# form of complex eigenvalue of a skew-symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $S$ be a matrix such that $S^T=-S$ and has complex eigenvalue $\lambda=a+i b$, then which is true:

a) $a$ = 0;

b) $b$ = 0.

Comment: Hello - any thoughts? Do you have a guess? Have you seen a similar question elsewhere?

Comment: If $S$ be a real matrix then for any nonzero eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $S$ we must have, $\lambda = -\bar{\lambda}$ and thus $a = 0$.
What about if $S$ be complex?

Comment: Look up the proof for the case of a real matrix and see how it works out for this case.

Comment: Try looking at an example, like $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. If only one of the two answers is correct, one example should let you determine which it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $S$ is a generic complex skew-symmetric matrix, neither (a) nor (b) is correct. This should be obvious: if one of the two options is correct, by considering $iS$, the other option must be correct too. Yet, (a) and (b) cannot both be correct, because there are clearly some skew-symmetric matrices with nonzero eigenvalues.